# content shrink when windows minimized

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
 #header,
      #main,
      #sidebar,
      #footer {
        background-color: black;
         display:inline;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
      }
      #header,
      #footer {
        width:100%;
        height:25%;
      }

      #main {
        width:68%;
        height:50%;
        margin-right:2%;
      }
      #sidebar {
        width:30%;
        height:50%;
      }
    ....
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
```

hi,this code snippet shrink content when windows minimized. my wanted result is that when minimized it, the browser just have a scrollbar and the content will not move on to their place.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it with your code, but maybe setting `min-width` on body will do it.

```
body {
    min-width: 1170px;
}
```

1170px could of course be something else.

Comment: thanks min width works for me, but when my sidebar and content area have contents on it,the content goes under sidebar. and i want this result to work on IE7 and min-width does not work on IE7.